# LM1117 5 V regulator and 2 servos

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, voltage-regulator, servo, overheat

I just started my first PCB and I have a question. I want to use two servos (SG90s) and a 5 V regulator powered from a 7.4 V battery.

After all my calculations the temperature that is dissipated is 160°C, but that's the thing I can not understand. My first prototype that I made was done using the same servos and an Arduino Nano, and I didn't have any problem with overheating or something like that. Are my calculations bad or will my LM1117 be fried?

This is my configuration:

[image]

My calculations:

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at 160 degrees?  How much power do you expect the servos to draw?

Comment: You can't calculate temperature without having some information on heatsinking, so, where did you get 160 °C from?

Comment: We don't know how you ended up with 160 degrees C. It would help to see what formulas you used and what values you plugged in to come up with 160.

Comment: Hi! I will post my calculations here.                                                                               
https://imgur.com/fI6Xbjv                                                                                                         In fact i want to use those SG90S servos to move a 3D printed device using a PID. Link for SG90S: https://www.smart-prototyping.com/MG90S-9g-metal-gear-digital-servo.html

Answer (score 3):

Those wee RC servos don't draw anything like 550mA on a **continuous** basis under normal conditions. If they did, they'd quickly burn up. They can, however, draw more than 550mA when stalled or when starting. From [this](https://nettigo.eu/products/sg90-small-hobby-servo) website:

[image]

So if they're lightly loading and running 10% of the time, the average current might be more like 15mA than 550mA.